# React frontend not receiving response from Django HttpResponse after successful request

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I'm working on an application with a React frontend and Django backend.

The frontend request is hitting the backend (and updating the db) but a response is not being returned to the frontend. I'm new to both Django and React so I haven't been able to debug it.

**React Frontend**

```
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken')

let headers = {
   "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
   "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 };

const qs = require('qs');
axios.post('/api/thing/new/', qs.stringify({thing_text: thing.thing_text}), {'headers': headers})
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(results)
  });
```

**Django Backend**

```
class ThingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = ['thing_text']

def thing_create(request):

    form = ThingForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    return JsonResponse({'foo':'bar'})
```

I've also tried returning a response with `return HttpResponse(status=204)` to no avail.

This is resulting in an error,

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: results is not defined
```

Which I interpret as nothing being returned to the frontend (though I could be wrong). Again, I know the backend is receiving the request because a record is created in the db.

Is there anything I should try to debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using React in a wrong way. A Promise is designed to return result at a later point of time. By the time your promise has been resolved or rejected. Try to resolve promise.

```
axios.post('/api/thing/new/', qs.stringify({thing_text: thing.thing_text}), {'headers': headers})
      .then(res=>(
        console.log(res.data)
      ))
```